# Using the latest source of ASP.NET MVC4 RC1 in a project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My machine has ASP.NET MVC3 and ASP.NET MVC4 beta1 installed.

I just donwloaded the latest source of ASP.NET MVC4 from http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets

How can I create a project in VS2010 that uses the assemblies created from this sourcecode?

Comment: The framework is bin-deployable; have you tried just dropping the libraries in the bin of the application or are you asking how to create a solution that compiles the MVC4 source? FWIW: "Because the binaries produced are bin-deployable, this allows you to compile your own builds and try product updates out as soon as they are checked-in." - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/03/27/asp-net-mvc-web-api-razor-and-open-source.aspx

Comment: I could build the source but am looking for a way to create an ASP.NET MVC project that uses the compiled assemblies.

Comment: You could just use the existing MVC4 project template and drop your custom built assemblies in the bin folder of your application *or* create your own project template that directly targets your custom assemblies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the source at http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/ and used the instructions there and there http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/documentation to get a compiling solution with working unittests.

I then created a new MVC4-Beta1 project in the solution. I removed references to

- System.Web.Mvc.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.dll

and added references to the corresponding projects in the  solution.

I then changed web.configs in the main folder and view folder.

```
 <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
```

was changed to

```
 <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
```

I can now compile the project and debug into the MVC-source.

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2009/02/03/using-the-aspnet-mvc-source-code-to-debug-your-app/). It's about an older version of ASP.NET MVC but the same applies for the MVC 4.0 Beta.

So here are the steps:

1. Create a new ASP.NET MVC 4 project in VS
2. Remove the reference of the System.Web.Mvc assembly (or whatever assembly you will be trying to debug)
3. Add a reference to the assembly you have compiled
4. In your web.config make sure that you remove the corresponding `<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, ...">` (the one with the strong name) or it will use the assembly from the GAC instead of your custom built one.